# Updating variable values in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I've have a basic question about updating the values of tensors via the tensorflow python api.

Consider the code snippet:

```
x = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,10), ... )
y = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,), ... )
W = tf.Variable( randn(10,10), dtype=tf.float32 )
yhat = tf.matmul(x, W)
```

Now let's assume I want to implement some sort of algorithm that iteratively updates the value of W (e.g. some optimization algo). This will involve steps like:

```
for i in range(max_its):
     resid = y_hat - y
     W = f(W , resid) # some update
```

the problem here is that `W` on the LHS is a new tensor, not the `W` that is used in `yhat = tf.matmul(x, W)`!  That is, a new variable is created and the value of `W` used in my "model" doesn't update.

Now one way around this would be

```
 for i in range(max_its):
     resid = y_hat - y
     W = f(W , resid) # some update 
     yhat = tf.matmul( x, W)
```

which results in the creation of a new "model" for each iteration of my loop !

Is there a better way to implement this (in python) without creating a whole bunch of new models for each iteration of the loop - but instead updating the original tensor `W` "in-place" so to speak?

Answer (score 8):

Variables have an assign method. Try:`W.assign(f(W,resid))`

Answer (score 2):

@aarbelle's terse answer is correct, I'll expand it a bit in case someone needs more info. The last 2 lines below is used for updating W.

```
x = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,10), ... )
y = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,), ... )
W = tf.Variable(randn(10,10), dtype=tf.float32 )
yhat = tf.matmul(x, W)

...

for i in range(max_its):
    resid = y_hat - y
    update = W.assign(f(W , resid)) # do not forget to initialize tf variables. 
    # "update" above is just a tf op, you need to run the op to update W.
    sess.run(update)
```

Answer (score 0):

Precisely, the answer should be `sess.run(W.assign(f(W,resid)))`. Then use `sess.run(W)` to show the change.

Comment: You forgot to define `sess`.